# Electrical rough-in Inspection JBox

Tags: electrical, wiring, inspection

Background: 
I live in Minneapolis. I am finishing my basement and in doing so will be adding a sub-panel. I am finishing up the details for the rough-in inspection (pre-panel install).

I was under the impression that everything should be ready for the receptacles, switches, and lights to be added. Meaning, for example, receptacles, and lights in series should be pigtailed but the actual outlets and lights shouldn't be connected.

I have multiple junction boxes as well to split a circuit to multiple lines. Given the above I would assume that I should make all connections. However, my father is adamant that they should be measured to length, cut off and labeled, but left disconnected.

Perhaps my google-fu is just terrible, but I can't find an answer either way.

Should all connections be made in a junction box for the rough-in inspection or should they be left to hang?

Comment: You're doing a lot of work to avoid a single phone call.  Stop searching the internet, and call your local building department.

Comment: Touché. I'll do so today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer ultimately lies with your AHJ (hint: call them), but where I am, everything has to be connected/pigtailed and ready for switches/outlets.